# Sharing Keychain Items in iOS

Tags: ios, security, keychain, sharing

I have application with bundle identifier as com.sakthi.app and app prefix ID as GHWEHDPRAG.I have stored some keychain items in this application using this identifier. Now I want to create another application where I can get keychain items stored in first application.

Tried creating bundle identifier as com.sakthi.apptemp with same app prefix ID. But I am not able to get the keychain items value.

Can you please tell how to access keychain items with same app prefix ID but different app bundle identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the Apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html

It details how to share items across two or more apps using a `keychain-access-groups entitlement`